# Sequence problem involving inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am triyng to solve this interesting problem, but I have no idea. I tried induction, but it didn't work.
Let $(x_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence, where $x_1=1$ and defined as follows:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+ \frac {1} {3x_n^2},$$ for every $n \ge 1$. Show that there exists a real number $c \gt 0$ so as $x_n \lt \sqrt[3] {n+c}.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is wrong. Define $y_n = x_n^3$. Then $y_1 = 1$ and
$$
 y_{n+1} = y_n + 1 + \frac{1}{3 y_n} + \frac{1}{27 y_n^2}
 > y_n + 1 + \frac{1}{3 y_n} \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
 y_n = y_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(y_{k+1} - y_k)
 > 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 + \frac{1}{3 y_k}\right)
 = n + \frac 13 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{y_k} \\
\Longrightarrow y_n - n > \frac 13 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{y_k}  \, .
$$

Now assume that $y_n < n + c$ for some real number $c > 0$ and all $n \in \Bbb N$. Then
$$
 c > y_n - n > \frac 13 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{y_k}
 > \frac 13 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k + c}
$$
which is a contradiction because the series on the right-hand side
diverges for $n \to \infty$.